# Taking most recent values in sum over date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table which has the following columns: DeskID *, ProductID *, Date *, Amount (where the columns marked with * make the primary key). The products in use vary over time, as represented in the image below.

Table format on the left, and a (hopefully) intuitive representation of the data on the right for one desk

[image: Table format on the left, (hopefully) intuitive representation on the right for one desk]

The objective is to have the sum of the latest amounts of products by desk and date, including products which are no longer in use, over a date range.

e.g. using the data above the desired table is:

[image: Desired table]

So on the 1st Jan, the sum is 1 of Product A

On the 2nd Jan, the sum is 2 of A and 5 of B, so 7

On the 4th Jan, the sum is 1 of A (out of use, so take the value from the 3rd), 5 of B, and 2 of C, so 8 in total

etc.

I have tried using a partition on the desk and product ordered by date to get the most recent value and turned the following code into a function (Function1 below) with @date Date parameter

```
select @date 'Date', t.DeskID, SUM(t.Amount) 'Sum' from (
    select @date 'Date', t.DeskID, t.ProductID, t.Amount
        , row_number() over (partition by t.DeskID, t.ProductID order by t.Date desc) as roworder
    from Table1 t
    where 1 = 1
    and t.Date <= @date
) t
where t.roworder = 1
group by t.DeskID
```

And then using a utility calendar table and cross apply to get the required values over a time range, as below

```
select * from Calendar c
cross apply Function1(c.CalendarDate)
where c.CalendarDate >= '20190101' and c.CalendarDate <= '20191009'
```

This has the expected results, but is far too slow. Currently each desk uses around 50 products, and the products roll every month, so after just 5 years each desk has a history of ~3000 products, which causes the whole thing to grind to a halt. (Roughly 30 seconds for a range of a single month)

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Please post table definition and data as a text not an image, so others can easily use it to tailor an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to the following should be faster:

```
select @date 'Date', t.DeskID, SUM(t.Amount) 'Sum'
FROM (SELECT m.DeskID, m.ProductID, MAX(m.[Date) AS MaxDate
  FROM Table1 m
  where m.[Date] <= @date) d
INNER JOIN Table1 t
ON d.DeskID=t.DeskID
AND d.ProductID=t.ProductID
and t.[Date] = d.MaxDate
group by t.DeskID
```

Answer (score 0):

The performance of TVF usually suffers. The following removes the TVF completely:

```
-- DROP TABLE Table1;
CREATE TABLE Table1 (DeskID int not null, ProductID nvarchar(32) not null, [Date] Date not null, Amount int not null, PRIMARY KEY ([Date],DeskID,ProductID));

INSERT Table1(DeskID,ProductID,[Date],Amount)
VALUES (1,'A','2019-01-01',1),(1,'A','2019-01-02',2),(1,'B','2019-01-02',5),(1,'A','2019-01-03',1)
,(1,'B','2019-01-03',4),(1,'C','2019-01-03',3),(1,'B','2019-01-04',5),(1,'C','2019-01-04',2),(1,'C','2019-01-05',2)
GO
DECLARE @StartDate date=N'2019-01-01';
DECLARE @EndDate date=N'2019-01-05';
;WITH cte_p
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT DeskID,ProductID
    FROM Table1
    WHERE [Date] <= @EndDate
),
cte_a
AS
(
  SELECT @StartDate AS [Date], p.DeskID, p.ProductID, ISNULL(a.Amount,0) AS Amount
  FROM (
    SELECT t.DeskID, t.ProductID
        , MAX(t.Date) AS FirstDate
    FROM Table1 t
    WHERE t.Date <= @StartDate
    GROUP BY t.DeskID, t.ProductID) f
  INNER JOIN  Table1 a
  ON f.DeskID=a.DeskID
  AND f.ProductID=a.ProductID
  AND f.[FirstDate]=a.[Date]
  RIGHT JOIN cte_p p
  ON p.DeskID=a.DeskID
  AND p.ProductID=a.ProductID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,a.[Date]) AS [Date], t.DeskID, t.ProductID, t.Amount
  FROM Table1 t
  INNER JOIN cte_a a
  ON t.DeskID=a.DeskID
  AND t.ProductID=a.ProductID
  AND t.[Date] > a.[Date]
  AND t.[Date] <= DATEADD(DAY,1,a.[Date])
  WHERE a.[Date]<@EndDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,a.[Date]) AS [Date], a.DeskID, a.ProductID, a.Amount
  FROM cte_a a
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t
      WHERE t.DeskID=a.DeskID
      AND t.ProductID=a.ProductID
      AND t.[Date] > a.[Date]
      AND t.[Date] <= DATEADD(DAY,1,a.[Date]))
  AND a.[Date]<@EndDate
 )
 SELECT [Date], DeskID, SUM(Amount)
 FROM cte_a
 GROUP BY [Date], DeskID;
```

Comment: That does seem to speed it up by about 75%, but if the date range is too large there is a recursion error building cte_a: `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: By default, the recursion level is 100. You can add OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) to the end of last SELECT to remove the limit.